# How to get access token from refresh token in gmail api in asp.net

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using oAuth 2.0 to authenticate gmail api v1 and getting the access token and refresh token but how to get access token using refresh token.

```
UserCredential credential;
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
       new ClientSecrets
       {
          ClientId = "my client id",
          ClientSecret = "my client secret"
       },
       new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailSend },
       "user",
       CancellationToken.None).Result;

// Create Gmail API service.
var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
   HttpClientInitializer = credential,
   ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
});

string RefreshToken = credential.Token.RefreshToken;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Google .Net client library handles all that for you.  Once you make your first request using your service it will request an access token using the refresh token.

Anwser: make a simple request to the Gmail API will fetch a access token if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it using .Net library. To do it manually,

POST

"client_secret=" + [ClientSecret] + "&grant_type=refresh_token" + "&refresh_token=" + [RefreshToken] + "&client_id=" + [ClientID]

To https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token

You need to replace data in square bracket with your details

Answer (score 0):

working code

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://mail.google.com/" };

UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
         new ClientSecrets
         {
            ClientId = "my client id",
            ClientSecret = "my client secret"
         },
         scopes,
        "user",
         CancellationToken.None).Result;
string RefreshToken = credential.Token.RefreshToken;//you will get Refreshtoken
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).